# Precedance over the browser back button from componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component, which is A and on success of some form filling, i route the user to the B component. Now when the user clicks on back button of browser, instead of going back to A component, i re route him to the Home Page

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/">
    <Root />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/home">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/form">
    <A />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/success">
    <B />
  </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

A.js

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log('component A is mounting')
}


onSubmit () {
   // on success of api
   this.props.history.push({
     pathname: '/success'
     search: '?viewType=success'
   })
}
```

B.js

```
 componentWillUnmount(){
  const viewType = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location?.search)?.get(
      'viewType'
    );
  if(viewType === 'success'){
      return this.props.history.push('/home')
  }
  return this.props.history.push('/')
 }
```

Even though i am pushing the route to `/home`, but i can see the A.js log of componentDidMount

I don't want to render the A.js from B history.push when browser back button is clicked